# Gaussian curvature of the paraboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I was trying to calculate the Gaussian curvature of the paraboloid with Cartesian equation
$z=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}$

I first took the parameterization $\psi(u,v)=(u,v,\frac{u^2}{a^2}+\frac{v^2}{b^2})$
and I found $K = \frac{4}{a^2 b^2 \left(1 + \frac{4u^2}{a^4} + \frac{4v^2}{b^4}\right)^2}$

I also wanted to calculate the first and second fundamental form with the parameterization $\psi(u,v)=(ar\cos(u),br\sin(v),r^2)$ to see if it was easier that way and I notice that the Gaussian curvature was zero, and not $K = \frac{4}{a^2 b^2 \left(1 + \frac{4u^2}{a^4} + \frac{4v^2}{b^4}\right)^2}$

**Why is that ? Regardless of the parameterization, the Gaussian curvature should be the same, Is the second parameterization wrong ?**

*

> (calculations)

- 

$\psi_u=(-ar\sin(u),0,0)$

$\psi_v=(0,br\cos(v),0)$

$E=a^2r^2\sin^2(u), F=0,G=b^2r^2\cos^2(v)$

$\psi_{uu}=(-ar\cos(u),0,0)$

$\psi_{vv}=(0,-br\sin(v),0)$

$\psi_{uv}=(0,0,0)$

$N(u,v)=(0,0,1)$

$e=f=g=0$

Comment: Look carefully at your parametrization. How is this a function of $u$ and $v$? You need to pay attention to details.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Oh! Yea it should be $(ucosv, usinv,u^2)$ ?

Comment: Close, but — again — check details.

Comment: @TedShifrin I didn't add the parameters $a,b$, is that what you meant ? Because I feel it isn't, and I am not sure what you mean. With the parameters we get  $(aucosv, businv,u^2)$

Comment: Right. Proceed.